# Prevent tab when setting Italic in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I'm making a Notes App for myself using `RichTextBox` and I am having some issues with the Font "Styling".
I bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to set the selected text to italic, which is working. But for some reason whenever I do so, it adds a tab, deleting all selected text.
The only case i could find with someone having that issue was solved by adding e.SuppressKeyPress=true; but that isn't working for me either.

```
private void txbMain_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if((e.KeyCode==Keys.B && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) || (e.KeyCode==Keys.F && e.Modifiers==(Keys.Control | Keys.Shift)))
    {
        FontHelper.Bold(this);
    }
    else if(e.KeyCode==Keys.I && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    {
        if (txbMain.SelectionFont != null)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            System.Drawing.Font currentFont = txbMain.SelectionFont;
            System.Drawing.FontStyle newFontStyle;
            if (txbMain.SelectionFont.Italic == true)
            {
                newFontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
            }
            else
            {
                newFontStyle = FontStyle.Italic;
            }
            txbMain.SelectionFont = new Font(
               currentFont.FontFamily,
               currentFont.Size,
               newFontStyle
            );
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What event are you using to trigger this code?

Comment: @colosso I updated the main post to show. Its just a KeyUp event in the RichTextBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination CTRL + I seems to be a default functionality of richtextbox to enter a tab. Your Text will be replaced even if you dont have any code or events on the richtextbox. So the problem is, that your event does get triggered after this default funtionality and the text is already deleted once the code reaches your text formatting.

**The easiest solution would be to use the KeyDown event instead of KeyUp.**